# How many requests can you make to Instagram safely?

Tags: javascript, instagram

I’ve been playing around with account data returned in JSON from https://instagram.com/graphql/query (using JS) and was worried if I made too many requests something bad might happen. My current project makes around 22 requests every 5 seconds, which seems fine but I just wanted to make sure there isn’t some sort of rule & I wouldn’t get banned.

tl:dr Is making 22 requests every 5 seconds  to an Instagram link safe, will I get banned?

Comment: this is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook's documentation, the new rate limit is 200 calls per hour, which you will have exceeded in less than a minute with your current setup.

Here is the link to the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview#rate-limiting

> Starting with v3.3, the Instagram Graph API uses the Business Use Case Rate Limiting logic. When API calls exceed 200 impressions per hour, calls fail.

Comment: I'm not using the API, since they require you to have an account token which requires login credentials. Since that won't work with my project I'm just getting all the data I need out of the JSON provided by the link I wrote above. (I came across the link from some Goggling, but to my knowledge it's not a part of their regular api.) I was able to make over 500 requests in a few seconds without a problem, so there's definitely not a limit.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for that info.  I have been unable to find any information about this, so it may just require some scientific method based research haha.